# SharePoint hosted app: Break Role Inheritance with 'Manage' right returns Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-addin, access-denied, app-permissions

I have a SharePoint hosted app that I want to break the role inheritance of a list item in the app page (in tenant site). The app has "Manage" rights on the web (both tenant and host). The problem is that the break role inheritance on list item returns 401: Unauthorized.

I have simplified the JavaScript code and managed to regenerate the error with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var listID = getQueryStringParameter('listId');
    list = web.get_lists().getById(listID);
    context.load(list);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {test();},function(){});
});
function test() {
    var item = list.getItemById(id);
    context.load(item, 'RoleAssignments');

    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        alert('succeeded');
    }, function (cr,crev) {
        alert('failed: '+crev.get_message()); // here it returns Access denied.
    });
}
```

Which will fail with mesasge "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource". SharePoint logs on the server:

```
Permission check failed. asking for 0x4000000000000000, have 0xb03c0312ef
Exception occured in scope Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection._SerializeToJson. Exception=System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions permissionMask)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection.Init()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.<EnumerateChildItems>d__36.MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteChildItems(JsonWriter writer, Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJson(JsonWriter writer, Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJsonWithMonitoredScope(JsonWriter writer, Object value, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
```

Checking Microsoft article [App permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx) and permission levels in SharePoint shows that "Manage" right in apps is equal to "Design" permission level which does not have the "Enumerate Permissions" base permission by default. So does this mean that there is no way for a SharePoint app to modify permissions on a site?

**Update:**

If I change the app permissions to "Full Control" everything works fine.

Comment: You may use `FullControl` permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to.